# Xamarin forms Android SurfaceView - still video image left behind

Tags: android, surfaceview

In my Xamarin forms Android app, I play videos in view 1 and 16 in a matrix of 16 views using Android SurfaceView integrating with third-party video SDK, see screenshot below. Then I switch to 4 views. On switching, I stopped both videos first and then resume playing. It still plays video in view 1 which is correct. But it also shows a still video image left behind (from previous view 16). Th surface view of this image should have been removed. What could be the cause of the image?

I can clear a video or image and detach the camera using the following code. We do have such a command button Clear All.

```
public int ClearVideo(int cameraIndex)
{
    if (App.CameraToViewHolderDictionary.ContainsKey(cameraIndex))
    {
        var surfaceHolder = (ISurfaceHolder)App.CameraToViewHolderDictionary[cameraIndex];
        if (surfaceHolder != null/* && surfaceHolder.Surface.IsValid*/)
        {
            surfaceHolder.SetFormat(Format.Transparent);
            surfaceHolder.SetFormat(Format.Opaque);
        }
    }

    _videoViewModel.DetachCamera(cameraIndex);

    return 0;
}
```

However this code shouldn't be required when changing the size of matrix views. Please suggest a way to get rid of the image left behind. Thank you.

I understand that this may not be an issue of Xamarin forms. Please note that the app works on some Android versions such as Pixel 3 or emulators such as bluestacks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: are there any animations involved?

Comment: @whiraj Hi, no animations involved. Only plays live video on SurfaceView integrated with a third party SDK.

Comment: At the beginning of switching to a smaller siize matrix views, I can remove residual image(s) using                 surfaceHolder.SetFormat(Format.Transparent);
                surfaceHolder.SetFormat(Format.Opaque);

Comment: At the beginning of switching to a smaller size matrix views, I can remove residual image(s) which was out of the current matrix view using  surfaceHolder.SetFormat(Format.Transparent); and surfaceHolder.SetFormat(Format.Opaque); But I have the last view in black which doesn't play video. The surface holder should be still the same IntPtr value. It shouldn't be a problem. The problem "No video and black background" may be caused by my change above. I cleared all the videos which are out of the current matrix view. I don't know why only the last view has the problem.